# Haxe/OpenFL - Android crash because of BitmapData

Tags: android, bitmap, haxe, openfl

I'm developing a tile-based game for mobile platforms, written in Haxe (with OpenFL): it works like a charm when I try it for HTML5 or a desktop target (Mac OS), but it crashes in its Android version.

I don't get errors, but I figured out the line which causes the problem (if I remove the code from that line, the application works):

```
var bitm = Assets.getBitmapData("assets/grass0.png");
```

I tried to change the file path trying with

```
var bitm = Assets.getBitmapData("grass0.png"); // or:
var bitm = Assets.getBitmapData("/grass0.png");
// and so on...
```

But I just get errors about the non existence of the file, so the path is correct...as I wrote, I don't get errors, the app just crashes at the beginning.

**UPDATE #1**:
This is the log from `adb logcat -c` (the app is *com.sample.pokemon*):

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/audio_hw_primary(  118): select_output_device: AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER
D/dalvikvm(  668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4307K, 36% free 9522K/14692K, paused 3ms+9ms, total 60ms
D/dalvikvm(  668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 594K, 26% free 10955K/14692K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 42ms
D/dalvikvm(  668): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
D/dalvikvm(  668): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 34ms
D/dalvikvm(  668): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
D/audio_hw_primary(  118): select_output_device: AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/ActivityManager(  403): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.sample.pokemon/.MainActivity} from pid 668
I/ActivityManager(  403): Start proc com.sample.pokemon for activity com.sample.pokemon/.MainActivity: pid=4607 uid=10101 gids={50101, 3003, 1028}
V/SDL     ( 4607): Device: espresso10wifi
V/SDL     ( 4607): Model: GT-P5110
V/SDL     ( 4607): onCreate(): null
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libstd.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libstd.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libstd.so 0x41b21d80, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libregexp.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libregexp.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libregexp.so 0x41b21d80, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libzlib.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libzlib.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libzlib.so 0x41b21d80, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/liblime.so 0x41b21d80
I/OpenAL_SLES( 4607): alc_opensles_init
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/liblime.so 0x41b21d80
V/SDL     ( 4607): onResume()
D/libEGL  ( 4607): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 4607): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 4607): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4607): Enabling debug mode 0
V/SDL     ( 4607): surfaceCreated()
V/SDL     ( 4607): surfaceChanged()
V/SDL     ( 4607): pixel format RGB_565
V/SDL     ( 4607): Window size: 1280x752
I/SDL     ( 4607): SDL_Android_Init()
I/SDL     ( 4607): SDL_Android_Init() finished!
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libApplicationMain.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libApplicationMain.so 0x41b21d80
D/dalvikvm( 4607): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/libApplicationMain.so 0x41b21d80, skipping init
I/haxe plugin( 4607): Got Load Proc 5fed9394
I/haxe plugin( 4607): Got Load Proc 5fed9394
I/haxe plugin( 4607): Got Load Proc 5fed9394
I/haxe plugin( 4607): Got Load Proc 5fed9394
I/OpenAL_SLES( 4607): opensles_open_playback pDevice=0x58c5f008, deviceName=(null)
I/OpenAL_SLES( 4607): alc_opensles_probe DEVICE_PROBE
I/OpenAL_SLES( 4607): opensles_reset_playback pDevice=0x58c5f008
I/OpenAL_SLES( 4607): bits=16, channels=2, samples=1024, size=4096, freq=44100
I/OpenAL_SLES( 4607): create audio player
W/libc    ( 4607): pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed: Operation not permitted
I/OpenAL_SLES( 4607): playback_function started
I/OpenAL  ( 4607): _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN=2
V/SDL     ( 4607): onWindowFocusChanged(): true
I/ActivityManager(  403): Displayed com.sample.pokemon/.MainActivity: +507ms
I/SDL/APP ( 4607): Added joystick Android Accelerometer with device_id -2147483648
I/trace   ( 4607): Shader.hx:141: Compile failed.
I/trace   ( 4607): WARNING: 0:23: Calls to any function that may require a gradient calculation inside a conditional block may return undefined results
I/trace   ( 4607): WARNING: 1 compilation warnings.
I/trace   ( 4607): 
F/libc    ( 4607): @@@ ABORTING: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x593c3d88 passed to dlfree
F/libc    ( 4607): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 4621 (SDLThread)
I/DEBUG   (  113): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  113): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/espresso10wifixx/espresso10wifi:4.0.3/IML74K/P5110XWALD2:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  113): Revision: '9'
I/DEBUG   (  113): pid: 4607, tid: 4621, name: SDLThread  >>> com.sample.pokemon <<<
I/DEBUG   (  113): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/DEBUG   (  113): Abort message: '@@@ ABORTING: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x593c3d88 passed to dlfree'
I/DEBUG   (  113):     r0 00000027  r1 00000000  r2 00000008  r3 deadbaad
I/DEBUG   (  113):     r4 00000000  r5 5fb02c1c  r6 4002d000  r7 593c3d90
I/DEBUG   (  113):     r8 60008214  r9 00000011  sl 5fb03304  fp 60041cbc
I/DEBUG   (  113):     ip 593c3d90  sp 5fb02c18  lr 4012a91f  pc 40127e84  cpsr 60070030
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d0  2064657372666c64  d1  72726f6320666f20
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d2  64612064696c6176  d3  726f207373657264
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d4  4047000000000000  d5  3fc10c60fd000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d6  41c10c60fd000000  d7  3fc10c60fd000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d8  3fe0000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d16 3a38317930526f67  d17 3225737465737361
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d18 0000000000000603  d19 3fa555549c6765ab
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d20 be927e4f5c2d943e  d21 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d22 3e21ee9ea4546f42  d23 3fe0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d24 3c19d9ccf0000000  d25 3ea5abe1bdacb6e2
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d26 3c83854000000000  d27 3da603d2e5dcd5ed
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d28 3fefffefbf178516  d29 3e30828a237153c9
I/DEBUG   (  113):     d30 3fc2492492c0a16e  d31 4000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  113):     scr 80000010
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #00  pc 0001ee84  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #01  pc 0001c67c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #02  pc 00012365  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #03  pc 00011031  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1184)
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #04  pc 0000db77  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #05  pc 00049f14  /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/liblime.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #06  pc 000404d4  /data/app-lib/com.sample.pokemon-1/liblime.so
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02bd8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02bdc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02be0  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02be4  40154310  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02be8  401478b5  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02bec  5fb02bfe  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02bf0  40151264  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02bf4  401511c4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02bf8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02bfc  4012a91f  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+34)
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c00  40129bc9  /system/lib/libc.so (_cleanup)
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c04  5fb02c1c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c08  4002d000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c0c  593c3d90  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c10  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c14  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #00  5fb02c18  5937e004  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c1c  fffffbdf  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c20  0000005a  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c24  4011b2ed  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c28  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c2c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c30  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c34  5fb02c5c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c38  40154110  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c3c  40125680  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone)
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #01  5fb02c40  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c44  4011b369  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #02  5fb02c48  5fb0306c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c4c  00000055  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c50  5fb02c5c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c54  5fb02cb1  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c58  5fb0305b  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c5c  20404040  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c60  524f4241  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c64  474e4954  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c68  6e69203a  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c6c  696c6176  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c70  64612064  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c74  73657264  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c78  726f2073  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c7c  64646120  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c80  73736572  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          5fb02c84  20666f20  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02bfc 4012a91f 40129bc9 5fb02c1c 4002d000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c0c 593c3d90 df0027ad 00000000 5937e004  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c1c fffffbdf 0000005a 4011b2ed ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c2c 00000000 00000003 5fb02c5c 40154110  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c3c 40125680 00000000 4011b369 5fb0306c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c4c 00000055 5fb02c5c 5fb02cb1 5fb0305b  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c5c 20404040 524f4241 474e4954 6e69203a  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c6c 696c6176 64612064 73657264 726f2073  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c7c 64646120 73736572 20666f20 72726f63  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c8c 20747075 636f6c62 7830206b 63333935  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c9c 38386433 73617020 20646573 64206f74  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02cac 6572666c 00000065 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02cbc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02ccc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02cdc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02cec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002cfe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002cff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d000 00000000 00000023 5bf8659a 5992e3c8  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d010 00000000 00000000 15400000 4252f944  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d020 5c2a1000 00000023 407f1da8 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d030 00000008 4002d048 408e37e9 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d040 00000000 0000002b 4002d008 4002d070  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d070 5bf85eae 00000000 15400000 4252f944  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d080 43de3400 42eccefa 012bb38b 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d090 00730041 00610069 0055002f 00750072  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d0a0 0071006d 00000069 00000000 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d0b0 5bf86200 5992e3c8 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d0c0 43de3400 42eccefa 5c2a1000 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4002d0d0 407f1da8 00000001 00000008 4002d0f0  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near r7:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3d70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3d80 00000000 00000000 6e702e32 00000251  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3d90 5935dcd0 672f7374 73736172 00000241  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3da0 73740067 00000239 40154190 40154190  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3db0 68676972 702e3074 65737361 612f7374  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3dc0 74657373 72672f73 30737361 676e702e  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3dd0 00000030 0000002a 7461642f 70612f61  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3de0 6f632f70 61732e6d 656c706d 6b6f702e  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3df0 6e6f6d65 612e312d 00000058 0000004a  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e00 402e1d88 00000001 593c3ec0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e10 00000000 33523252 ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e20 0000019b 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e40 3252676e 00000199 401541a0 401541a0  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e50 613a3532 74657373 7461642f 70612f61  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e60 6f632f70 61732e6d 656c706d 6b6f702e  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     600081f4 60007a90 016a0016 65737361 32257374  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008204 61726746 2e307373 00676e70 01000015  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008214 65737361 672f7374 73736172 6e702e30  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008224 00000067 0112800d 5ffab508 00000011  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008234 60008214 012a8019 5ffa85f8 00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008244 00000003 00000001 00000002 60008270  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008254 013a0015 6000822c 00000004 60007a90  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008264 4a51e5a5 00000000 01560009 600082ac  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008274 600082f4 016e800e 5ffab508 00000004  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008284 60007ba4 0100800d 5ffab508 00000004  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60008294 60007ba4 010a800d 5ffab508 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     600082a4 60007bdc 011a0015 6000829c 00000004  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     600082b4 60007ba4 4d08f2ba 00000000 012a800d  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     600082c4 5ffab508 00000002 60007c18 0142800d  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     600082d4 5ffab508 00000002 60007c18 0152800d  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     600082e4 5ffab508 00000011 60008214 01620016  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb032e4 00000011 60041c01 00000011 60041c01  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb032f4 60041d04 6000b601 5fb03370 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03304 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03314 60041d14 60041cbc 5fb03370 5fb034d0  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03324 00000000 5fb03460 60006d18 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03334 5febc064 00000005 00000011 60008214  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03344 00000011 60041cbc 00000011 60008214  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03354 5ff18c0c 00000011 00000011 60041cbc  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03364 00000000 00000000 5ff0ef00 60041d04  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03374 5febb71c 60041cd4 00000005 5fb03530  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03384 5ff62478 5ffac5a4 60006d18 5fb03554  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb03394 5fe96dac 5fb03401 409dc1e8 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb033a4 5ff626bc 00000000 5ff685d8 0000001b  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb033b4 00000030 5935dfb0 401197cf 5ff65b68  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb033c4 5fedcecc 6000c648 000001a0 5fb03510  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb033d4 58b24008 00000014 5935df98 58b2407c  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041c9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041cac 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000015  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041cbc 65737361 672f7374 73736172 6e702e30  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041ccc 00000067 013a000d 5ffab508 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041cdc 5ff626bc 0152800d 5ffab508 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041cec 60007bdc 0162000d 5ffab508 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041cfc 5ff626bc 0100800d 5ffab508 00000011  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d0c 60008214 01028039 5ffa0d40 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d1c 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d2c 00000000 5ffed254 ffffffff 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d3c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d4c 0112800d 5ffab508 00000011 60008214  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d5c 014e8009 5ffa78c8 60041f20 015e8011  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d6c 5ff9d818 0000019b 0000019b 60041d80  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d7c 016a019e 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     60041d8c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3d70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3d80 00000000 00000000 6e702e32 00000251  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3d90 5935dcd0 672f7374 73736172 00000241  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3da0 73740067 00000239 40154190 40154190  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3db0 68676972 702e3074 65737361 612f7374  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3dc0 74657373 72672f73 30737361 676e702e  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3dd0 00000030 0000002a 7461642f 70612f61  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3de0 6f632f70 61732e6d 656c706d 6b6f702e  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3df0 6e6f6d65 612e312d 00000058 0000004a  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e00 402e1d88 00000001 593c3ec0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e10 00000000 33523252 ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e20 0000019b 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e40 3252676e 00000199 401541a0 401541a0  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e50 613a3532 74657373 7461642f 70612f61  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     593c3e60 6f632f70 61732e6d 656c706d 6b6f702e  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02bf8 00000000 4012a91f 40129bc9 5fb02c1c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c08 4002d000 593c3d90 df0027ad 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c18 5937e004 fffffbdf 0000005a 4011b2ed  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c28 ffffffff 00000000 00000003 5fb02c5c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c38 40154110 40125680 00000000 4011b369  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c48 5fb0306c 00000055 5fb02c5c 5fb02cb1  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c58 5fb0305b 20404040 524f4241 474e4954  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c68 6e69203a 696c6176 64612064 73657264  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c78 726f2073 64646120 73736572 20666f20  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c88 72726f63 20747075 636f6c62 7830206b  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02c98 63333935 38386433 73617020 20646573  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02ca8 64206f74 6572666c 00000065 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02cb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02cc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02cd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     5fb02ce8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127e64 461ce00b 2b006823 e026d1fb b12468e4  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127e74 21014a18 6011447a 4b1247a0 24002027  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127e84 f7fc7018 2106ea2a ec80f7fd 5180f04f  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127e94 91042006 460aa902 94039402 e82cf7fd  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127ea4 46224629 f7fd2002 f7fce838 2106ea16  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127eb4 ec6cf7fd f7fb2001 6960eec2 d1dc2800  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127ec4 bf00e7d4 deadbaad 00029190 ffffff9c  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127ed4 0002c540 0002c524 2400b510 4669b088  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127ee4 9002aa04 94014620 94039400 ef7af7fc  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127ef4 db0642a0 b1139b07 1c419806 98069106  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127f04 4620e000 bd10b008 4b1eb40e b5f0491e  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127f14 447bb082 585eaf00 021cf107 4b04f852  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127f24 68352101 f852607d 31015b04 d1fa2d00  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127f34 320e008a 0507f022 0220f107 0d05ebad  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127f44 4669603a 0224f107 9400466d 4c04f852  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     40127f54 f8453204 2c004f04 f8dfd1f8 f853c030  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a8fc 4a0e4b0d 41f0e92d 447b4680 589c2600  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a90c 686768a5 f9b5e007 2b00300c 4628dd02  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a91c 430647c0 3f013554 6824d5f5 d1ef2c00  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a92c e8bd4630 bf0081f0 000266ce ffffffc4  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a93c 43f0e92d f502fb01 4b16461e 4916460f  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a94c 447bb087 46149001 aa012001 92039502  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a95c 90049505 681a585b b1124698 f0094630  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a96c 4630fd20 f7ffa903 4681fe9c 0000f8d8  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a97c 4630b110 fd22f009 0f00f1b9 9c05d005  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a98c 1b284639 eab2f017 46204604 e8bdb007  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a99c bf0083f0 00026686 ffffff60 46036842  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a9ac 29001e51 da016041 bb98f000 f8126802  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a9bc 601a0b01 00004770 4a104b0f 4604b570  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a9cc 589b447b 461e6819 f009b109 6860fcea  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a9dc 2d001e45 da046065 f0004620 4605fb7f  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     4012a9ec 6822e003 5b01f812 68336022 4620b113  
I/DEBUG   (  113): 
I/DEBUG   (  113): memory map around fault addr deadbaad:
I/DEBUG   (  113):     bea17000-bea38000 rw- [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   (  113):     ffff0000-ffff1000 r-x [vectors]
I/BootReceiver(  403): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
W/InputDispatcher(  403): channel '423bcdb0 com.sample.pokemon/com.sample.pokemon.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  403): channel '423bcdb0 com.sample.pokemon/com.sample.pokemon.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
D/Zygote  (  116): Process 4607 terminated by signal (11)
D/dalvikvm(  403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1436K, 23% free 12431K/16028K, paused 100ms, total 100ms
W/InputDispatcher(  403): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '423bcdb0 com.sample.pokemon/com.sample.pokemon.MainActivity (server)'
I/ActivityManager(  403): Process com.sample.pokemon (pid 4607) has died.
I/WindowState(  403): WIN DEATH: Window{4241dc30 u0 SurfaceView}
W/ActivityManager(  403): Force removing ActivityRecord{42246720 u0 com.sample.pokemon/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
I/WindowState(  403): WIN DEATH: Window{423bcdb0 u0 com.sample.pokemon/com.sample.pokemon.MainActivity}
D/dalvikvm(  403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 21% free 12787K/16028K, paused 100ms, total 100ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  403): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.330MB for 294932-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 215K, 22% free 12862K/16320K, paused 89ms, total 90ms
D/dalvikvm(  403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 584K, 24% free 12470K/16320K, paused 90ms, total 90ms
I/ActivityManager(  403): Start proc com.google.android.gsf.login for service com.google.android.gsf.login/com.google.android.gsf.loginservice.GoogleLoginService: pid=4630 uid=10050 gids={50050, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 1006, 3002, 3001, 2001, 3006}
W/System  ( 1422): Ignoring HTTP header field 'User-Agent' because its value is null
I/ActivityManager(  403): No longer want system:ui (pid 4334): empty #17
W/InputMethodManagerService(  403): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4607 uid 10101
```

Here my library versions:

```
actuate: 1.8.3 [1.8.6]
box2d: [1.2.3]
haxeui: [1.7.14]
hscript: [2.0.4]
hxcpp: [3.2.102]
layout: [1.2.0]
lime-samples: [2.3.0]
lime: [2.4.5]
openfl-samples: [2.2.2]
openfl: [3.1.1] 3.1.3 3.1.4
svg: [1.0.8]
swf: [1.8.9]
yagp: [1.1.4]
```

I've tried with OpenFL 3.1.4 (last version installed) but I get this error when I run `sudo openfl test android`:

```
/usr/lib/haxelib/openfl/3,1,4/openfl/display/BitmapData.hx:5: characters 7-44 : Type not found : lime.graphics.cairo.CairoImageSurface
```

So I've tried with OpenFL 3.1.3 but I get another error:

```
/usr/lib/haxelib/openfl/3,1,3/openfl/display/Loader.hx:4: characters 7-35 : Type not found : lime.system.BackgroundWorker
```

(I didn't get any error with OpenFL 3.1.1)

**P.s.**:
I tried using another image but it didn't solve the problem.
I checked that the images are correctly in the `Export/android/bin/assets/assets/` folder.
The images I'm using are ~4KB 32x32 .png files.

**UPDATE #2**:

I get the same problem using a sample project (*PiratePig*).
I tried to use a Windows 7 computer with the Android emulator, too, but it didn't solve it.

I decided to report this problem to the [OpenFL Community](http://community.openfl.org/t/android-crash-because-of-bitmapdata-bug/6353).

Comment: Post the crash log from your logcat output via ```adb logcat``` and your library versions from ```haxelib list```. Even if the app crashes on launch, details about the crash will normally appear in logcat. Is that image present when you check the ```export/android``` folder? Does getBitmapData work for other images in your project? Try some other versions of ```openfl``` or ```lime``` using ```haxelib set <library> <version>``` and report a bug if it works in older versions.